# Release build still allows to step-through code, why?

Tags: c#, c++, build, release, step-through

I have published a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ENMFPdotNet/) to NuGet but while testing it, I found out that I can still step-through the C++ classes even though it is the 'Release' build.

Can you explain why is this and how it can be fixed ?

Comment: C# or C++ ? In either case drop PDBs and you'll be almost there for both...

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I have already removed the PDB. And it's a C++ CLI library.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen when source code is not available, e.g. on a different machine.